# How to create user in Symfony with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin?

Tags: php, plugins, symfony1, content-management-system, doctrine

I need to create users through code, is possible?

Only found in google the form with console, and not is what i need.

Thanks.

symfony version 1.4.6
sfDoctrineGuardPlugin version 1.0.4

Comment: Have you seen http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-simple-registration-with-sfdoctrineguardplugin

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$user = new sfGuardUser();
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setPassword($password);
$user->setEmailAddress($email);
$user->save();

//Bonus: connect user to a group
$userGroup = new sfGuardUserGroup();
$userGroup->setUser($user);
$userGroup->setGroupId(1);
$userGroup->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have installed the plugin execute this comand:

```
./symfony guard:create-user admin password
```

with this user, in your backend you can add more non-superadmin users